# Magento add flash message for move from wishlist to cart

Tags: php, magento, cart

I'm trying to add a flash message upon moving of an individual item from a wishlist to the cart in Magento. This already happens when all items are added to cart, but not when an individual item is moved from the wishlist to the cart. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: To clarify, this is something I want to add for when a single item is added from wishlist to cart. When you click the "Add all to cart" from the wishlist, it does give you a message, but it does not give this message when just one item is individually added to cart from the wishlist.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Magento Enterprise? 
I checked the code base and it looks like they are already showing a message for moving a single item from wishlist to cart.

```
app/code/core/Enterprise/Wishlist/controllers/SearchController.php:260
```

Comment: If you click the "Add all to cart" button on the wishlist, then yes it does display a flash button, but if you click the individual "Add to cart" buttons next to each product in the wishlist it does not display anything.